# SendMessage (backspace) not working!

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
Private Const WM_KEYDOWN = &H100
Private Const WM_KEYUP = &H101
Private Const VK_BACKSPACE = &H8

Private Overloads Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wp As IntPtr, ByVal lp As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function
```

And i send message like this:

```
SendMessage(windHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, CType(VK_BACKSPACE, IntPtr), CType(&HC0510001, IntPtr))
SendMessage(windHandle, WM_KEYUP, CType(VK_BACKSPACE, IntPtr), CType(&HC0510001, IntPtr))
```

I have allso tried with keybd_event just before this one:

```
Call keybd_event(&H8, MapVirtualKey(&H8, 0), 0, 0)
Call keybd_event(&H8, MapVirtualKey(&H8, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
```

Can anyone help?
Thank you!

Comment: Keyboard messages are posted, not sent.  You cannot get it reliable, you can't control the state of the modifier keys.  keybd_event() is okay but the app must have the focus.  Same thing with SendKeys.

Comment: @Hans Passant i know that but all other keys are working fine! ENTER, CTRL+V, CTRL+A, UP, DOWN,... only Backspace is bothering me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it... it was my fault! my function didnt fireing because of some crazy old code boolean!

so if anyone ever need this the above sendmessage works fine for backspace!

sorry guys :)